# Using tuple as a dictionary key in Python

Tags: python, tuples

I am trying to work with a dictionary with tuples of n values as keys. I want to find tuples whose 2nd value is 10 (for example)

```
('HI', '10', '10', '10', '10', '10000', 'true', '0.5GiB', '8', '100000s', '100MiB')
('HI', '100', '10', '10', '10', '100', 'false', '0.5GiB', '8', '100000s', '100MiB')
('HI', '100', '10', '10', '10', '1000', 'true', '0.7GiB', '8', '1000s', '100MiB')
```

Any ideads how I can do it? THanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For that particular scenario, you'd have to iterate over all of the keys and test them against your predicate:

```
results = set(k for k in your_dict if k[1] == '10')
```

If you wanted to do this more quickly for repeated lookups and you knew ahead of time what field(s) you'd be checking, you could build indices that map between values for a particular index in each tuple to the keys that have a given value:

```
from collections import defaultdict

index_2nd = defaultdict(set)
for k in your_dict:
    index_2nd[k[1]].add(k)
```

And then you could just use that to look up a particular value:

```
results = index_2nd['10']
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't, not easily. You'd have to loop through all keys to check for those that match:

```
matching = [key for key in yourtupledict if key[1] == '10']
```

If you need to do this a lot in your application, you'd be better off creating indices; dictionaries or similar that map the second value in all your keys to specific keys.

Answer (score 2):

Use `iterkeys()` to iterate over keys

```
d = {(1,2,3):1,(1,2,4):2,(2,2,3):3}

for k in d.iterkeys():
    if k[0] == 1:
        print k
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def find(key_element):
    return [value for key, value in a.iteritems() if len(key) > 1 and key[1] == key_element]
```